# Webpack with Angular2 and VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, npm, webpack

How can I use Visual Studio 2015 in combination with Webpack and Angular2. I have created a working Angular2 App with VS but now I have added the Webpack to build my app. I wan't to use the IIS Express to debug all of my code even c# web api in a single point and I don't want to use the external HTTP Server. Has anyone done this? How can I run webpack scripts to make work this code

```
 <!-- 1. Configure Webpack -->
<% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.isDevServer && htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.HMR !== true) { %>
<!-- Webpack Dev Server reload -->
<script src="/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
<% } %>
```

With the external HTTP Server my build and app works fine.

Answer (score 6):

This is a very good guide on how to set up Angular2 and webpack inside a Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET Core project that runs WebAPI.

https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2016/08/27/how-to-set-up-angular-2-and-webpack-in-visual-studio-with-asp-net-core/

[The complete starter pack is hosted on github](https://github.com/FabianGosebrink/ASPNET-Core-Angular2-Webpack-StarterTemplate). I found that this code actually works a bit better than if you just follow the steps in the guide, so refer to this code if there are any problems.

If you perfer ASP.NET MVC5, this is a template that I have found very useful: This is a setup with Visual Studio, Angular2, Webpack and ASP.NET MVC 5: https://github.com/burkeholland/webpack-demo/tree/master/webpack-demo.

Comment: has anyone tried it also with the "old" asp.net webapi

Comment: As alternative you can use a proxy to use the api in the webpack server. here a helpful link http://nikolay.rocks/2016-01-13-connect-webpack-to-backend

Comment: @cpiock see my expanded answer

Comment: For MVC I found just installing webpack2 globally, adding a webpack.config file and finally running webpack -w at a command prompt was all I needed to do to use webpack2 via VS - great stuff!